# Can't get docker to accept request over the internet

Tags: linux, networking, jenkins, docker

So, I'm trying to get Jenkins working inside of docker as an exercise to get experience using docker. I have a small linux server, running Ubuntu 14.04 in my house (computer I wasn't using for anything else), and have no issues getting the container to start up, and connect to Jenkins over my local network.

My issue comes in when I try to connect to it from outside of my local network. I have port 8080 forwarded to the serve with the container, and if I run a port checker it says the port is open. However, when I actually try and go to my-ip:8080, I will either get nothing if I started the container just with -p 8080:8080 or "Error: Invalid request or server failed. HTTP_Proxy" if I run it with -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080.

I wanted to make sure it wasn't jenkins, so I tried getting just a simple hello world flask application to work, and had the exact same issue. Any recommendations? Do I need to add anything extra inside Ubuntu to get it to allow outside connections to go to my containers?

EDIT: I'm also just using the official Jenkins image from docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

Then to connect to jenkins you will have to connect to (in essence you are doing port forwarding):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080 or http://localhost:8080
```

If you are just running this:

```
docker run jenkins
```

You can connect to jenkins using the container's IP

```
http://<containers-ip>:8080
```

The Dockerfile when the Jenkins container is built already exposes port 8080

Comment: I'm running `docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins`, and can connect just fine using `http://localhost:8080`. The issue I'm having is I want to be able to connect to jenkins when I'm on a different network, say home at my parents place. I want to be able to put in my routers WAN IP, and connect to my container. This isn't working. I do have the port forwarded to my server setup in my router's config, and when I run a port checker it says the port is open, but when I try to go to `http://my-wan-ip:8080` the browser just hangs, and my containers don't get the request.

Comment: check your iptables on your host? are you blocking most ports? you probably need to allow 8080 from the outside

Comment: Port 8080 is allowed in my iptables.

Comment: try enabling ip forwarding `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Site has a great amount of information on container networks.
https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking

*"By default Docker containers can make connections to the outside world, but the outside world cannot connect to containers."*

You will need to provide special options when invoking docker run in order for containers to accept incoming connections.

Use the `-P` or `--publish-all=true|false` for containers to accept incoming connections.

The below should allow you to access it from another network:

```
docker run -P -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. At this point I just want to get it to work to prove a point to myself haha But it's really weird. The port is open, and accessible from the internet, however Ubuntu doesn't seem to want to allow outside connections to go to any docker containers. If I connect to it from my laptop on the same network, it works fine. But as soon as I try to connect with a device on another network (my phone for example), it either gives me a proxy error in the browser, or just hangs forever.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this [line in my iptables?](http://i.imgur.com/v8yqLNf.png)

Comment: It looks like your forward chain has a default policy of `ACCEPT`. It doesn't appear you have any drop policies, which is a good thing. What does the `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` command return?

Comment: I already have it set to 1. Which is what it should be right?

Comment: Yup. Perhaps Docker is setup correctly and your router is not setup correctly. Did you setup your router to forward the inbound traffic to the Docker Host?

Comment: Do you also have multiple NIC cards on your machine (e.g. `eth0` , `eth1`)?

Comment: The router _should_ be setup correctly. I mean.. I have ssh forwarded to my host as well, so I know that part was done right.

Comment: And I only have `eth0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87628/discussion-between-the-fluffy-prophet-and-peter-hauge).

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc was this solved? I am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you can connect to Jenkins over local network from a machine different than the one docker is running on but not from outside your local network, then the problem is not docker. In this case the problem is what ever machine who is receiving outside connection (normally your router, modem or ...) does not know to which machine the outside request should be forwarded.

You have to make sure you are forwarding the proper port on your external IP to proper port on the machine which is running Docker. This can be normally done on your internet modem/router.

Comment: I tried setting up another service running on 8080, just to see, and it works if it isn't a docker container.

Comment: So it's only services running inside a container that's causing me problems. Even though the ports are bound correctly to the host.

Comment: is this "another service" running on the same machine which runs docker container? do you access this other service both from inside and outside your network?

Comment: Yes, but I only ran one of them at a time. I just wanted to see if it was a docker specific issue, or something else. And it was just a minecraft server haha I was able to connect to it from outside of my local network (over the internet)

Comment: ok then you maybe have to make sure jenkins is listening to all IPs, mostly a `0.0.0.0` should be used.